# how to upload cropped image to firebase realtime database from imageCropper in Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app

```
imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
    this.croppedImage = event.base64;
    console.log(' Image is cropped');
    return this.croppedImage;
}
```

I want to crop image and upload to firebase realtime database using ionic 4 . 
any help is apreciated. 
i am using ImageCropper plugin.

Comment: You need to upload image using base64 or you have to upload using file object?

Comment: any approach is welcome. how can i upload using file object?